# What's the semantic of "@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)"?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, css, media-queries

I happened to use the below CSS hack for WebKit-based browsers, according to http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #my-id { height: 100%; }
}
```

It works. But, later I found that it doesn't work in production environment. I found out that it is due to CSS optimizer trimming the space after `and`. The below CSS is not recognizable by Chrome.

```
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #my-id { height: 100%; }
}
```

So, what does exactly the `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` mean?

I know `@media screen`, but I haven't used `and` in a CSS file before.

Why is the space character after `and` necessary?

Comment: Technically, I don’t think that’s a CSS hack. It’s not exactly what those language features were intended for, but it pretty effectively identifies WebKit, thanks to its use of `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0`. One of the not-so-hacky hacks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144706/is-there-a-version-of-yui-compressor-that-deals-correctly-with-media-queries

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The media query itself is, like you say, used to filter WebKit because it uses a `-webkit-` property.

Chrome is simply a little strict when you say it can't recognize

```
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
```

because that is in fact invalid CSS. The space after the `and` keyword is significant. This is clearly stated in the [CSS3 media query spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax):

> #### EXAMPLE 20
>
> The following is an malformed media query because having no space between ‘and’ and the expression is not allowed. (That is reserved for the functional notation syntax.)
>
> ```
> @media all and(color) { … }
> ```

The functional notation refers to things like `url()`, `rgb()` and `rgba()`. As you can see there is no space between the function name and the opening parenthesis in these examples.

`and` is not a function, but simply a keyword to say that the media query must match the medium you specify, **and** that the layout engine must satisfy the expression you place after it. The parentheses around `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0` simply denote it as an expression.

*Addendum:* yes, that does mean your CSS optimizer has a bug ;)

Comment: I think I just came across this same bug - YUI Compressor.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Ooh, perhaps you should file a report then.

Comment: [Just did](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/ticket/2528087), though apparently I'm a dolt at writing ["WikiSyntax"](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuilibrary/wiki/WikiSyntax)... I need MarkDown everywhere, dammit

Comment: @MattBall - Same issue w YUI

Answer (score 13):

Here is a quick workaround with YUI compressor's special comment.

```
@media screen and/*!*/(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { ... }
```

The issue is fixed in the current (2.4.5) version

https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/CssCompressor.java#L180

Comment: +1 for this quick fix. I am using the 'yuicompressor-maven-plugin', which is still using 2.4.2.

Comment: fix works great with ajaxminifier ... Thanks a lot.  syntax: @media screen/*!*/and/*!*/(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)

Answer (score 0):

Only use this:

```css
@media(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

}
```

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: Use this to apply CSS only for WebKit based browser , think about it as if ( webkit ) do something